# jQuery putting function instead of value in selector for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

When selecting an element using a for loop, for example:

```
jQuery('[data-slide=' + slideInfo[index].hideIDs[i] + ']').slideUp()
```

This is the error I am getting.
It seems like it's getting a function from somewhere instead of the number inside `slideInfo[index].hideIDs[i]`

```
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-slide1=function each(iterator, context) {
    try {
      this._each(iterator, context);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e != $break) throw e;
    }
    return this;
  }]
```

Here is the full code:

```
        var slideInfo = [
            {
                hideIDs: [0,1,2],
                showIDs: [3,4,5]
            },
            {
                hideIDs: [3,4,5],
                showIDs: [6,7,8]
            }
        ]

        jQuery('[data-slide] [type=button]').on('click', function() {

            for(var i in slideInfo[index].hideIDs) {
                jQuery('[data-slide=' + slideInfo[index].hideIDs[i] + ']').slideUp();
            }

            for(var i in slideInfo[index].showIDs) {
                jQuery('[data-slide=' + slideInfo[index].showIDs[i] + ']').slideDown();
            }

            index++;
        });
```

Comment: You probably should be generating quotes in the selector around the id value.

Comment: Where is `index` defined?

Comment: @freedomn-m why would that make any difference? If the value is causing a problem, it'll do so regardless of how it ends up in the selector string.

Comment: Also don't use `for ... in` for iterating through arrays - use a plain `for` loop with a numeric index.

Comment: It should be quite easy to debug it, regarding expected `index` and `i` value compare to the ones you get, and so why this cause invalid selector. I guess this is because the `for...in` loop

Comment: Looks like the issue is down to how `index` is defined